# awk zip rows like python zip

Tags: awk

Hi I am looking to zip 2 lines, preferable with awk.

Suppose we have this output

```sh
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7875          53        7523           8         298        7579
Swap:            99           0          99
```

I am looking to display it as such.

```
total: 7875, used: 53, free: 7523, shared: 8, buff/cache: 298, available: 7579
```

I have tried this based on another question.

```sh
free -m | awk '$1=="Mem:" || $1=="total" {key=$0; getline; print key ", " $0;}'
```

But it put the lines after each other instead of "zipping" them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with `free` command.

```
free -m | 
awk '
  FNR==1{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ arr[i]=$i }
  }
  FNR==2{
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
      printf("%s%s",arr[i-1]":" OFS $i,i==NF?ORS:",")
    }
  }
'
```

OR try following:

```
free -m | 
awk '
  FNR==1{
    split($0,arr)
  }
  FNR==2{
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
      printf("%s%s",arr[i-1]":" OFS $i,i==NF?ORS:",")
    }
  }
'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
free -m |                             ##Running free -m command and sending its output to awk command as an input here.
awk '                                 ##Starting awk program from here.
  FNR==1{                             ##If this is first line then do following.
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ arr[i]=$i }   ##Traversing through all fields and created array arr with index of field number and value is current field value.
  }
  FNR==2{                             ##If this is 2nd line then do following.
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){               ##Traversing through all fields from 2nd field onwards.
      printf("%s%s",arr[i-1]":" OFS $i,i==NF?ORS:",") ##Printing array value along with current field value as per OP requirement here.
    }
  }
'
```

Comment: very nice, thank you. I accepting it as it but do you think there is a way to add comma and colons? I have tried to put a comma in the printf at different places but the result wasnt as expected.

Comment: @TheFool, yeah we could do it, let me edit it in a min or so.

Comment: @TheFool, code has been edited as per request, please do check it once.

Comment: its perfect. I just made `", "` to get that extra white space. This also shows how I could put other things at those places. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Using `cat file` in place of `free -m` (which I don't have) for this example:

```
$ cat file |
awk -v RS= -v OFS=', ' '{for (i=1; i<=6; i++) printf "%s: %s%s", $i, $(i+7), (i<6 ? OFS : ORS)}'
total: 7875, used: 53, free: 7523, shared: 8, buff/cache: 298, available: 7579
```